# ¿Cómo calcular en r el promedio de una columna con varios criterios de otras columnas?

Tags: base-de-datos, r, rstudio, r-dplyr, tidyverse

a partir de estos datos horarios, necesito encontrar el valor de NA, calculando el promedio de Temp del día anterior y el siguiente a la misma hora (1200).

El formato de los datos es el siguiente:
Donde n es el número de día del año. La hora está sin formato (0 = 00:00, 100 = 1:00, etc).

| Date | n | Hour | Temp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 09/01/2016 | 9 | 600 | 8.4 |
| 09/01/2016 | 9 | 700 | 8.2 |
| 09/01/2016 | 9 | 800 | 7.8 |
| 09/01/2016 | 9 | 900 | 8.7 |
| 09/01/2016 | 9 | 1000 | 13.6 |
| 09/01/2016 | 9 | 1100 | 16.6 |
| 09/01/2016 | 9 | 1200 | 19.7 |
| 10/01/2016 | 10 | 1200 | ***NA*** |
| 11/01/2016 | 11 | 1200 | 18.9 |
| 11/01/2016 | 11 | 1300 | 20.9 |
| 11/01/2016 | 11 | 1400 | 23.3 |
| 11/01/2016 | 11 | 1500 | 24.3 |

Son muchos NA en periodos diferentes, por lo que estoy tratando de obtener un código que me permita calcular los promedios del día anterior y posterior a la hora donde hay un NA.

Gracias

Comment: El promedio por día es bastante sencillo: `df %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(mean_temp = mean(Temp))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira a ver si este código te vale, lo voy comentando.

Tus datos:

```r
df <- tibble::tribble(
         ~Date,  ~n, ~Hour, ~Temp,
  "09/01/2016",  9L,  600L,   8.4,
  "09/01/2016",  9L,  700L,   8.2,
  "09/01/2016",  9L,  800L,   7.8,
  "09/01/2016",  9L,  900L,   8.7,
  "09/01/2016",  9L, 1000L,  13.6,
  "09/01/2016",  9L, 1100L,  16.6,
  "09/01/2016",  9L, 1200L,  19.7,
  "10/01/2016", 10L, 1200L,    NA,
  "11/01/2016", 11L, 1200L,  18.9,
  "11/01/2016", 11L, 1300L,  20.9,
  "11/01/2016", 11L, 1400L,  23.3,
  "11/01/2016", 11L, 1500L,  24.3,
  "12/01/2016", 11L, 1200L,  NA,
  "13/01/2016", 11L, 1200L,  31.7
  )

df
#> # A tibble: 14 x 4
#>    Date           n  Hour  Temp
#>    <chr>      <int> <int> <dbl>
#>  1 09/01/2016     9   600   8.4
#>  2 09/01/2016     9   700   8.2
#>  3 09/01/2016     9   800   7.8
#>  4 09/01/2016     9   900   8.7
#>  5 09/01/2016     9  1000  13.6
#>  6 09/01/2016     9  1100  16.6
#>  7 09/01/2016     9  1200  19.7
#>  8 10/01/2016    10  1200  NA  
#>  9 11/01/2016    11  1200  18.9
#> 10 11/01/2016    11  1300  20.9
#> 11 11/01/2016    11  1400  23.3
#> 12 11/01/2016    11  1500  24.3
#> 13 12/01/2016    11  1200  NA  
#> 14 13/01/2016    11  1200  31.7
```

Lo primero es convertir `Date` a formato date de R y seleccionar las temperaturas con `NA`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
# Convierte a formato dia
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(Date_fix = as.Date(Date, "%d/%m/%y"))

# Encuentra NAs
nas <- df2 %>%
  filter(is.na(Temp))
```

Ahora seleccionamos los dias de antes y de despues a los días que tienes con `NA`:

```r
# Datos para el promedio
prom <- df2 %>% filter(
  Date_fix %in% nas$Date_fix +1 |
    Date_fix %in% nas$Date_fix -1
) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  select(Date2 = Date_fix, 
         Hour, 
         temp_prom = Temp)
```

Ahora vamos a unir con el dataset de `NAs` por hora, y para cada hora con `NA` nos quedamos con aquellos registros del dia anterior y posterior. Por ultimo, hacemos el promedio:

```r
newtemp <- nas %>%
  # Une por hora
  left_join(prom, by = "Hour") %>%
  # Crea diferencia de dias
  mutate(dif=Date_fix - Date2) %>%
  # Filtra dias antes o despues 
  filter(abs(dif) == 1) %>%
  # Haz promedio por Date y Hora, que es la clave del registro `NA`
  group_by(Date, Hour) %>%
  summarise(new_temp = mean(temp_prom))
```

Por último, pegamos al dataset inicial el promedio calculado. En este caso en una columna nueva `Temp_end` para que se vea el proceso completo:

```r
# Hora final
df %>%
  left_join(newtemp) %>%
  mutate(Temp_end = if_else(is.na(Temp), new_temp, Temp))
#> Joining, by = "Date"
#> # A tibble: 14 x 6
#>    Date           n  Hour  Temp new_temp Temp_end
#>    <chr>      <int> <int> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 09/01/2016     9   600   8.4     NA        8.4
#>  2 09/01/2016     9   700   8.2     NA        8.2
#>  3 09/01/2016     9   800   7.8     NA        7.8
#>  4 09/01/2016     9   900   8.7     NA        8.7
#>  5 09/01/2016     9  1000  13.6     NA       13.6
#>  6 09/01/2016     9  1100  16.6     NA       16.6
#>  7 09/01/2016     9  1200  19.7     NA       19.7
#>  8 10/01/2016    10  1200  NA       19.3     19.3
#>  9 11/01/2016    11  1200  18.9     NA       18.9
#> 10 11/01/2016    11  1300  20.9     NA       20.9
#> 11 11/01/2016    11  1400  23.3     NA       23.3
#> 12 11/01/2016    11  1500  24.3     NA       24.3
#> 13 12/01/2016    11  1200  NA       25.3     25.3
#> 14 13/01/2016    11  1200  31.7     NA       31.7
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>